# Reactjs - Cannot read the property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to render a class component using conditional rendering. The class component has a state value that is by default set to false. In the class, a function called `start()` performs some operation and based on the results, it will call a function `verifyTheIdentity()` that has `setState()`. But I am not able to call the `verifyTheIdentity()` from `start()`.

```js
import React from "react";
import * as faceapi from "face-api.js";
import web3 from "../web3";

class recognize extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      verified: false
    }
    this.verifyTheIdentity = this.verifyTheIdentity.bind(this);
    // this.start = this.start.bind(this);
  }
  verifyTheIdentity() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        verified: true
      }
    })
  }
  async start() {
    ///////////////////CODE FOR FACE RECOGNITION///////////////////////////////
    let name = result.toString();
    console.log(name);
    const pattern = new RegExp(/^unknown/)
    console.log(pattern.test(name))
    if (pattern.test(name) === false) {
      document.getElementById("verifier").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("verifier").onClick = this.verifyTheIdentity;    //This is where I am going wrong.
    }
    else
      document.getElementById("verifier").disabled = true;

  })
})
    }
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.verified == false ? <div><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" /><br />
        <button disabled id="verifier" >Verify</button></div> :
        <div><br /><br /><br /><br /><p>Verified</p></div>}
    </div>

  )
}
}
export default recognize;
```

And this is the error I get.

```js
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property
'verifyTheIdentity' of undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need bind at all, if you use arrow function.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            verified: false 
        }
    }
    verifyTheIdentity = () => {
        //code
    }   
    start = async () => {
       // code 
    }
```

Try this, it should work.

or 
remove commented code,
add in constructor (remove // from the line)

```
this.start = this.start.bind(this);
```

Comment: I actually tried the first method. I didn't get the **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'verifyTheIdentity' of undefined**  error, however, when I console logged it, `this.state.verified` still returned false. However, when I used `document.getElementById("verifier").onClick = this.verifyTheIdentity();` , it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can replace this line by below one

```
document.getElementById("verifier").onClick = this.verifyTheIdentity;
```

like this

```
 document.getElementById("verifier").onClick = this.verifyTheIdentity();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to Javascript Syntax violation -

> "Calling a function without parenthesis"

To fix the issue, either call the function `verifyTheIdentity()` with proper syntax as:

```
document.getElementById("verifier").onClick = this.verifyTheIdentity();
```

Or, assign the function to a varialbe and call it:

```
const test = verifyTheIdentity() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                verified: true
            }
        }) 
    };
document.getElementById("verifier").onClick = this.test ;
```

For your understanding, see the example:

```js
function Test(){
   alert(1);
}  

//Test;    //It won't work
Test();  // It will work
```